# Creating a more visually pleasing bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, visualization, tableau-desktop

I'm currently building a dashboard in Tableau Desktop based on the Forbes Top 50 highest paid athletes from May 2021-May 2022. I have a bar chart showing the top 5 earners, but I want to remove their names from the bottom and place a small circular picture of their face, club team logo and then the respective amount, all above the bar.

I've attempted to delete the bottom row where it shows the players names, but it doesn't work. I have the player name and total earned but am unsure how to format the player face and team logo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Tableau image role in version 2022.4

[image]

You need to prepare the data with the images in a specific way though, Tim explains more precisely here : https://youtu.be/37xBp2BCQgw

Comment: wow, thanks for the great visual. I'll try it out and see how well it works.

Comment: refer the steps in the video